# Json forming using c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Hi My json structure is like this

```
{
  "OutputParam": [
    {
      "param1": "John",
      "param2": "Doe",
      "param3": "BT",
      "param4": [
        {
          "subparam1": "00002",
          "subparam2": "True",
          "subparam3": "-",
          "subparam4": "-",
          "subparam5": "data goes here"
        },
        {
          "subparam1": "00003",
          "subparam2": "True",
          "subparam3": "-",
          "subparam4": "-",
          "subparam5": "data goes here"
        },
        {
          "subparam1": "00004",
          "subparam2": "False",
          "subparam3": "111",
          "subparam4": "message",
          "subparam5": "-"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and the classes which I get from http://json2csharp.com/ is as follows

```
public class Param4
{
    public string subparam1 { get; set; }
    public string subparam2 { get; set; }
    public string subparam3 { get; set; }
    public string subparam4 { get; set; }
    public string subparam5 { get; set; }
}

public class OutputParam
{
    public string param1 { get; set; }
    public string param2 { get; set; }
    public string param3 { get; set; }
    public List<Param4> param4 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<OutputParam> OutputParam { get; set; }
}
```

now the issues is I want to pass above Json as API output in c# API, I tried list and var but so far not able to return the above mentioned Json, can any one help or at least give a direction?

Comment: The json file should be called 'OutputParam'.

Comment: yes it should be called output param

Comment: It's a little unclear - are you having problems getting the _right_ JSON, or just converting your classes to JSON at all?  If the latter, you need to serialize your classes as JSON.  One way to do so is to use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).  If the former, perhaps post the JSON that you _are_ getting, so we can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: In the Json api's there are a lot of serializers and deserializers you should use.

Comment: a small sample of code will be great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is small sample of code that can help you

```
public RootObject1 Get(int id)
    {
        RootObject1 rt = new RootObject1();
        OutputParam pr = new OutputParam();
        Param4 cr = new Param4();
        rt.OutputParam = new List<OutputParam>();
        pr.Param4= new List<Param4>();
        pr.Param1= "AB";
        rt.OutputParam = new List<OutputParam>();
        cr.Param6 = "aceee";
        pr.Param4.Add(cr);

        rt.OutputParam.Add(pr);
        return rt;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return as per your example using Web API a method such as

```
public RootObject GetRootObject()
{
   return new RootObject();
}
```

Would do it, assuming the request to the API asked for JSON in the [content negotiation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation) - the web api will derserialise your object into JSON auto-magically

Comment: can you please explain it in little detail like how can i form above json using this class

Comment: just to clarify the intent: You have a populated RootObject class and what you want to do in your webmethod is return this class as JSON? If so the code above is all you need. Have you tried out this method in your API? What happens when you call it?

Answer (score 0):

your webservice c# prolly return an xml whith your json as string in? this is the default

so you have different choice

go for xml or add this line to your methode

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```